# make a real ajax call with jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine

I want to use Jasmine for two things, test a function that does a real ajax call, and acquire the callback data from the ajax call for use in additional jasmine tests.

This is what I have so far:

Javascript function:

```
function getAttributeInfo(selectedLayer){

    // Get layer attributes
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/geoserver/oqplatform/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName='+ selectedLayer +'&outputFormat=json',
        success: function(data) {
            // pass the data into a global variable
            foo = data;
            // EDIT
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

The test:

```
it("an ajax test", function() {

    var ajaxFunction = getAttributeInfo(SVIRLayerNames[0]);
    // creating spied callback
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy('callback');

    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (req) {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        return d.promise();
    });

    // EDIT
    //ajaxFunction.fetch(callback);
    ajaxFunction(callback);

    // everything after this does not seem to execute
    var fakeData = callback.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
});
```

If I console log the foo variable after 5 seconds I can see that the ajax request was made and the data is available in the foo variable

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if its not clear, I want to get the data back from the ajax call into jasmine

Comment: It seems like some code is missing. `getAttributeInfo` does not return anything, so `ajaxFunction` in the test is `undefined`, meaning it has no method `fetch`.

Comment: I have updated the example with 'retune data;', but it is still unclear to me how I can return the promise from the ajax function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days looking into this, my big take away is that Jasmine is a great tool, but the documentation is terrible. I found it very difficult to simply understand what a spy is and when a it should be used.

My solution was to not use a spy at all.

```
beforeAll(function(done) {

    var mySyncFunction = function () {

        var layerName = 'foobar';
        var layerRequest = getAttributeInfo(layerName);

        layerRequest.success(function(layerResponse) {
            // Pass data from the response into a global variable to be tests
            // I can also check for things like the API version number.
        });

        layerRequest.done(function() {
           // Alert Jasmine that the AJAX call is done
           done();
        });
    };

    mySyncFunction();
}
```

And in the getAttributeInfo function I added `return` just before `$.ajax`

**UPDATE**

```
...
beforeAll(function(done) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/my/data',
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            foo = response
            done();
        },
    dataType: 'html'
    });
});

////////////////
// Some tests //
////////////////

it("meets some requirement", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        var name = foo[i].fields.name;
        expect(name).toBeDefined();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good question and answer, but you forgot when I can call my expect